# Can a contract stop part-time employees (but not full time employees) getting a second part-time job?

Tags: england-and-wales, discrimination, academia, research

I am currently considering a funded PhD post. They allow both full-time and part-time applications. They were very clear that if you do the PhD part-time, you at *not* allowed to do any other paid work, including teaching at the university (though you can teach for free), but if you were full-time there were no such restrictions on extra work. Their stated rationale is that they want to allow those with caring responsibilities to be able to apply, but not for people to pick up lucrative side work in parallel.

I would like to do the PhD 60% of fulltime equivalent, and continue a separate unrelated teaching role I currently have at about 10% fulltime equivalent.

Is this ban on second jobs for parttime employees enforceable in a contract ? If it doesn’t impact the ability to do the part-time job they pay you for (or any other conflicts eg using privileged information), can they stop you taking another part-time role? It seems bizarre they will seek to prevent a part-timer doing extra work that doesn’t hit the fulltime threshold, but permit a full timer to do even more. At a stretch, feels like indirect discrimination against those with caring responsibilities that can’t do the programme fulltime.

In England. University PhD role, and private teaching for the other role.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Legally working , Two remote jobs at same time](https://law.stackexchange.com/questions/85382/legally-working-two-remote-jobs-at-same-time)

Comment: Thanks, it doesn’t quite answer but is similar. I edited this question to clarify about only part-time employees would be prevented but not full-time. Other differences are that they are separate fields, both jobs would be part time and less than fulltime combined, and it doesn’t specify but I am in UK.